# How to write in smallcaps in chead of article class?

Tags: formatting, small-caps

I want to write few words in small caps. But it's not working in `\chead`

```
\chead{\textbf{\textsc{\Huge Small Caps Text}}}
```

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you use `fancyhdr`, with `article` class, you will get a warning

> LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

Hence, you have to fake the shapes. This can be done by adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   %%<------------ add this
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\textbf{\textsc{\Huge Small Caps Text}}}
\setlength{\headheight}{21pt}   %% needed to accomodate the large head
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or use a font that has small caps.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\textbf{\textsc{\Huge Small Caps Text}}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{21pt}   %% needed to accomodate the large head
\begin{document}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```